# how to find closest locations between 5m to 10m range from array of locations in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

this was my code and i want nearest locations from my current location in the range of 10meters and i want to add all the nearest locations with details of the person in response also add in array.thanks

and this is my response from server

```
{
    born = 0;
    completed = 0;
    "emergency_id" = "-1";
    eyes = "";
    feet = 0;
    "first_name" = Neil;
    glasses = No;
    hair = "";
    inch = 0;
    language = "<null>";
    "last_name" = Ferris;
    latitude = "30.1456987";
    longitude = "76.69916";
    marks = "";
    "member_id" = 21634;
    picture = "";
    "profile_id" = 5826;
    type = 1;
    updated = "2015-09-16 06:32:08";
    weight = 0;
}
```

like the above i am getting 5000 users from server ,after i filtering with 10 meters distance through my current location i need to display list in table view who are in below 10 meters range

```
- (void)getdata
{
    NSString * apiURLStr =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<MY API URL>"];

    NSString *outputStr = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:apiURLStr] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    NSDictionary *response;
    if (outputStr == nil)
    {
        return;

    }

    NSData* data = [outputStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSError *error;
    response = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];

    NSMutableArray *array=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    CLLocation *closestLocation = nil;
    for (NSDictionary *dict in response)
    {
        NSString *latitude=[dict valueForKey:@"latitude"];
        NSString *longitude=[dict valueForKey:@"longitude"];

        CLLocation *location = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:latitude.doubleValue
        longitude:longitude.doubleValue];

        [array addObject:location];
    }

    CLLocationDistance closestLocationDistance = DBL_MIN;

    for (CLLocation *location in array)
    {
        if (!closestLocation) {
            closestLocation = location;
            closestLocationDistance = [currentUserLocation distanceFromLocation:location];
            continue;
        }
        CLLocationDistance currentDistance = [currentUserLocation distanceFromLocation:location];
        if (currentDistance < closestLocationDistance)
        {
            closestLocation = location;
            closestLocationDistance = currentDistance;
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"closestLocation %@",closestLocation.description);
    NSLog(@"closestLocationDistance %f", closestLocationDistance);
}
```

Comment: with this code your array will always contain only one element. You should parse your "response" first

Comment: yes i had already passed my response with method [self getdata];

Comment: and the latitude and longitude should be showing  all response from response array.

Comment: no, you create array with only one element(first in response, as I understand). You should iterate through all elements in response manually, convert every element to CLLocation and write it to the array

Comment: place breakpoint on "for" line and check the "array", you will see that it contain  only one element

Comment: yes i done that one also ,see in code NSArray *array=[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:[latitude doubleValue] longitude:[longitude doubleValue]], nil];

Comment: i am checking that one also showing all response in array dude

Comment: you want to say that [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:[latitude doubleValue] longitude:[longitude doubleValue]] will returns a set of objects for you?

Comment: can you print here the array content?

Comment: that was so long data bro approximately 5000+ values in array so here it is not possible to print i think?

Comment: my whole code is posted please check and let me do favour

Comment: ok, it's bit different code. Only issue I see, it's you store the annotations in your array([array addObject:annotaton];), but later you try to use it as the CLLocation (for (CLLocation *location in array))

Comment: JSONValue - what parser you use?

Comment: http://pastie.org/10441638
I've test it, everything works

Comment: thanks for answer bro,but i want list of closest locations in below 10 meters range.

Comment: @guruprasadgudluri i see there difference in pastie code which lgor have suggested, it is the right code as lgor have fixed error in [array addObject:location]; instead of  [array addObject:annotaton]; so please edit your question code from igor code

Comment: i am edited my question with new code and please let me do favor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> thanks for answer bro,but i want list of closest locations in below 10 meters range.

```
NSMutableArray *locationsInRange = [NSMutableArray new];

for (CLLocation *location in array)
{
    CLLocationDistance currentDistance = [currentUserLocation distanceFromLocation:location];
    if (currentDistance < 10)
    {
        [locationsInRange addObject:location];
    }
}

NSLog(@"locations in 10 metters %@",locationsInRange.description);
```

Comment: i am getting null result is locations in 10 metters ( ),the array is null

Comment: and also i want their name ,userid and profilepic as mentioned in the response above in my question.

Comment: I've test this code, check if you have correct currentUserLocation. "and also i want their name" it's concept how to get locations you need, write additional code to get everything what you need

Comment: this is my current location: lat:30.714512 long: 76.699919 i have checked  and result should be null

Comment: i need  users who are in below 10 meters range with their details what it could be coming in response

Comment: yes, I've check the code, it's work as expected, to get names or other data you should use custom objects instead of CLLocation on parse stage, and save in this custom object CLLocation to calculate distance later and "name" or other data you need